# how to push comment using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code as below, a form validation for comment box on my web, I already linked it to validation javascript where the code notify them when they're input a wrong email structure or type the comment box over 140 char, and didn't insert the name it was like regex, and i would like to make another javascript internal to push the comment so after the user write the comment it will shown on the page, as shown bellow. But I got a little problem, where it couldn't show up my comment. Please if you read this question, tell me where did I do it wrong. Thank you so much

```
<script>
                    var comment = [];

                    var name= document.getElementById("nama");

                    var email= document.getElementById("email");

                    var message= document.getElementById("komen");

                    var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

                    function insert(){
                        comment.push("Nama :" + name.value);
                        comment.push("Email : " + email.value);

                        comment.push("Message : " + message.value);

                        clearAndShow();

                    }
                     function clearAndShow (){

                        name.value = "";

                        email.value = "";

                        message.value = "";

                        messageBox.innerHTML = "";

                        messageBox.innerHTML += " " + comment.join("<br/> ") + "<br/>";

                     }</script>

                <section>
                    <form name="RegForm" action="" onsubmit="return validation()" method="post">  

                        Nama Anda :</br><input type=text name="Name" id="nama" size="35" placeholder="Nama"><br /><br> 
                        Email :</br><input type=text name="EMail" id="email" size="35" placeholder="E-mail"><br /><br> 
                        Komentar :</br><textarea rows="12" name="Comment" id="komen" cols="100" wrap="virtual" placeholder="Pesan"></textarea><br/><br>

                            <input type="submit" onclick="insert()" value="send" />
                            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset">
                    </form><br />
```

Comment: You have no `#display` element, so `messageBox.innerHTML =` will throw an error.

Comment: I think you want at use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) rather than getting each field by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing your `#display`. Add that should be fine:

```js
let comment = [];
let name = document.getElementById("nama");
let email = document.getElementById("email");
let message = document.getElementById("komen");
let messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

insert = () => {
  // You can push these all at once
  comment.push(
    `Nama :${name.value}`,
    `Email : ${email.value}`,
    `Message : ${message.value}`);
  clearAndShow();
}

clearAndShow = () => {
  name.value = "";
  email.value = "";
  message.value = "";
  messageBox.innerHTML = "";
  messageBox.innerHTML += " " + comment.join("<br/>") + "<br/>";
}
// remove this
document.querySelector('form[name=RegForm]').onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<section>
  <form name="RegForm" action="" method="post">
    Nama Anda :</br>
    <input type=text name="Name" id="nama" size="35" placeholder="Nama">
    <br /><br> Email :</br>
    <input type=text name="EMail" id="email" size="35" placeholder="E-mail">
    <br /><br> Komentar :</br>
    <textarea rows="12" name="Comment" id="komen" cols="100" wrap="virtual" placeholder="Pesan"></textarea><br/><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="insert()" value="send" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset">
  </form>
</section>
<div id='display'></div>
```